# Solution for $4^{2x+1}-3^{3x+1}=4^{2x+3}-3^{3x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm trying to get a solution for:

$4^{2x+1}-3^{3x+1}=4^{2x+3}-3^{3x+2}$

My main problem is that I don't know how to combine this potencys!

Ive also thought about another function that would bring me same difficulties:

$6^x=36*9.75^{x-2}$

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: For the second, you have $6^{x-2}=9.75^{x-2}$, so $x=2$

Comment: $4^{2x+3}-4^{2x+1} = 3^{3x+2}-3^{3x+1}$ $\implies$ $4^{2x}(64-4) = 3^{3x}(9-3)$ $\implies$ $16^x \cdot 60 = 27^x \cdot 6$ $\implies$ $...$

Comment: @RossMillikan could you please explain it a little bit further? Thanks

Comment: I just divided both sides by $36=6^2$  Now take the logs of each side and you get $(x-2)\log 6=(x-2)\log 9.75$  You must have $x=2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$4^{2x+1}-3^{3x+1}=4^{2x+3}-3^{3x+2}$$
$$4^{2x+1}-4^{2x+3}=3^{3x+1}-3^{3x+2}$$
$$4\cdot4^{2x}-4^34^{2x}=3\cdot3^{3x}-3^23^{3x}$$
$$60\cdot4^{2x}=6\cdot3^{3x}$$
$$10\cdot4^{2x}=3^{3x}$$
$$10\cdot16^{x}=27^{x}$$
$$10=(27/16)^{x}$$
$$\log_{10} 10=\log_{10} (27/16)^{x}$$
$$1=x\log_{10}(27/16)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{\log_{10}27-\log_{10}16}$$

Comment: Edited to show log base 10.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, we have
$$
4^{2x+1}-3^{3x+1}=4^{2x+3}-3^{3x+2} \implies\\
3^{3x+2}-3^{3x+1} = 4^{2x+3}-4^{2x+1} \implies\\
(3-1)3^{3x+1} = (4^2 - 1)4^{2x+1} \implies\\
2\cdot 3^{3x+1} =  5\cdot 3\cdot4^{2x+1} \implies\\
3^{3x} = 5 \cdot 2^{4x+1}
$$
I think that's the simplest we can get it.  From there, I suppose we'd have to solve using logs.

That is, let $\log(x)$ be the logarithm of your choosing.  We have
$$
\log(3^{3x}) = \log(5 \cdot 2^{4x+1}) \implies\\
3x \log(3) = \log(5) + (4x+1)\log(2) \implies\\
(3 \log 3 - 4 \log 2)x = \log 5 + \log 2 \implies\\
x = \frac{\log 5 + \log 2}{3 \log 3 - 4 \log 2} = \frac{\log(10)}{\log(3^3/2^4)} = \frac{1}{\log_{10}27 - \log_{10}16}
$$

Comment: Very good answer but could you explain it further with the log? Thanks

Comment: That's easy $$3x \log 3 = \log 5 + (4x+1) \log 2$$

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Note, here "log" is natural log, as mathematicians always write.

Comment: @GEdgar I explicitly say "let $\log$ refer to the logarithm of your choosing".  Regardless of the choice of logarithm, the answer is the same. A good general point, though.